# Как употребить слово "лабутены" в единственном числе?

Tags: морфология

Как употребить слово "лабутены" в единственном числе?
Лабутена или лабутен?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У каждого из этих вариантов свой недостаток, связанный с противоречивостью грамматического рода: "*лабутен*" противоречит видовому наименованию изделия (туфля), а "*лабутена*" - полу своего создателя месье Лубутена. Поэтому я бы предложил рассматривать лабутены как неделимую (типа ножниц) или собирательную (типа печенья) сущность и именовать каждую туфлю, которой можно, например, запустить в кого-нибудь, "**лабутениной**" (ср. "печениной"); если запустить по-доброму - "**лабутенинкой**" (ср. "печенинкой").